# Best way to setup Routes in ASP.NET Core 2 Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm looking for the best way to do my routing in my web Api.

Currently my routes are like these:

```
[Route("api/branch/{branchId}/products")]
[Route("api/branch/{branchId}/clients")]
```

In order to consume the api, I need to send a token with the authorization header.   The token has the user branchId as a claim.

With my current setup I would need to give the user the branchId to the user in order to consume the api, I prefer not.

What would be the best way to implement the solution just by using the token with this route?

```
[Route("api/branch/products")]
```

I know that I would be able to extract the token values in every controller using the UserManager, but that would be to much repeating code

What would you suggest?

Thanks
Alberto Lopez

Comment: The client calling your API should be able to provide the branchId. The client should be able to build this route. Your problem is that you somehow think the branchId is private information, and since you say it is private information than your routes cannot a {branchId} part

Comment: Is the branch Id relevant to the action being called? If the branch id is meant to identify the client and is part of the Authorization header (and eventually in the User claims) then it is not needed in the URL

Answer (score 0):

Write middleware to extract the claim value from the token and store it in the current http context.

`HttpContext.Items["branchId"] = branchIdFromToken;`

Then you can just use it anywhere where the request context is available by calling `HttpContext.Items["branchId"]`.

A sample for writing middleware and extracting claims from the token (different purposes though) can be found [here](https://shellmonger.com/2015/07/20/writing-custom-middleware-for-asp-net/).